# Pop Up / Hover Directions or Menu Above iFrame

Tags: html, css, iframe, popup

I'm trying to word this correctly but as always: I'm a novice so forgive mistakes/confusion.

I have created an iframe that embeds a client's main site within their tumblr, meaning you don' have to leave tumblr to access the site. I did this because the old designer had installed a "latest item in the shop" widget which no longer worked & I wanted similar but the information needed didn't exist anymore.

What I would like is a pop-up or hover over box that says: return to blog or carry on to nameofsite.com. Even the links above the iframe would be adequate for now but I can't think how to do it without messing with the appearance of the embedded site.
[image: Clicking here goes to]

http://2000adonline.tumblr.com/website

As usual, I think I have developed a wildly complicated issue when a simple redirect would have sufficed! Ah well! Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you hover over the I-frame?

Comment: Yes, specifically over the 2000AD logo at the top. Is that not do-able? I know my ignorance is showing but I am making this up as I go along, all comments & criticisms are welcome, the more I know/learn, the better, nothing you say will be a waste of time so feel free to chip in!

Comment: You can only hover over the whole iframe and make it do things, not parts inside of it.

Answer (score 2):

A pop-up can be made for the i-frame, but it can only be for the whole i-frame, not elements inside of it. To make a pop-up, wrap the i-frame and pop-up HTML in a `<div>`:

```
<div id="iframe">
<iframe src="http://www.w3.org"></iframe>
<div class="over">Return to blog or carry on to nameofsite.com</div>
</div>
```

Then you need to style the iframe and pop-up:

```
iframe{
    width:500px;
    height:500px;
}
#iframe:hover  .over{
    opacity:1;
}
.over{
    opacity:0;
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:40px;
    -o-transition:.3s;
    -ms-transition:.3s;
    -moz-transition:.3s ;
    -webkit-transition:.3s;
    transition:.3s  ;
}
#iframe{
    position:relative;
    width:500px;
 }
```

When the div #iframe is hovered over, the pop-up fades in at the top.
[See this working JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ImagineStudios/tTnLx/)

Comment: Hey thanks I'll try this out & see how I get on. I'm always being told to try out my code on places like JSFiddle before I implement them & I never do, I'm terrible for just editing live sites! Such a bad habit! Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, looking good, though I have the feeling I have forgotten something. Here's the final Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xxVicxx/LEL5v/ if you have any comments or suggestions they would be appreciated. Thanks you so much for your help, really nice work!

Comment: @JustADesignDabblingBeginner It looks good. I suggest you make the pop up on the bottom instead of the top as it covers the nav bar. In .over CSS change top:0px; to bottom:0px;